# Is it possible to hide the action bar only from the main activity and not from fragments?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-fragmentactivity

I have an application with a single activity and some fragments. I want to hide the action bar from the main activity page, but I want to have the action bar/toolbar on the fragments with a back button. Is it possible to happen? Or do I have to create more activities? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean? fragments can only be shown inside an activity, they're not separate from the activity, but from each other...

Comment: I know that fragments are part of the activity, but I was wondering If it is possible to hide the action bar from the main activity page, but not from the next fragment pages. I want this to happen because on my main activity page there is a bottom navigation bar with the menu and I don't need the action bar. But I need an action bar/toolbar with a back button to the other fragment pages.

Comment: why do you need the whole action bar/toolbar for a back arrow? just put an `ImageButton` with a back arrow to get this...